# MPI_Send/Recv dynamically allocated arrays in C

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to write a Finite Volume Solver in C using MPI and cannot seem to get the passing of the arrays correct with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. I need all of the workers to do some computation on their part of the array and then send that sub-array back to the master to put the sub-array back together and compare the approximation with a known solution. The structure of the fvm solver and code is correct, I've checked the serial code against a known solution. Below is the code where I try and pass the sub-arrays back to master and receive them in master. I've configured Valgrind with mpi support, and the memcheck tool does not like the allocation in the send_output_MPI function. Which agrees with what happens when I try and run the program. Mpiexec aborts with signal code: 6.

Below is full sample code. The passing of arrays is in the recv_output_MPI and send_output_MPI functions, where I try and pass the subarrays back to master.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "fvm.h"
#include "lab_mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    double tt0, tt1;

//  MPI variables
    int ierr; // MPI error flag
    int nProc, nWrs, myID, rc;

//-------------Start MPI------------------
    rc = MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    if ( rc != MPI_SUCCESS ) {
        printf( "Error starting MPI program. Terminating.\n" );
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
     }
    ierr = MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nProc );
    assert( !ierr );
    ierr = MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myID );
    assert( !ierr );
    nWrs = nProc - 1;
    assert( nWrs == nProc - 1 );

    if ( myID == MASTER ) {
        tt0 = MPI_Wtime( );
        master( nWrs, myID );
        tt1 = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("  Main MR timing = %lf sec on %i workers.\n", tt1 - tt0, nWrs );
        fflush(stdout);
    } else {
        ierr = worker( nWrs, myID );
        printf("  Worker %i exiting; ierr = %i\n", myID, ierr );
        fflush(stdout);
        if ( ierr != 0 )
            printf("  Worker %i exiting with ierr = %i\n", myID, ierr );
        fflush(stdout);
    }

//---------------End MPI-------------------------
    ierr = MPI_Finalize( );
    assert( !ierr );
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}

/* master MPI function
 * reads input file, packs ints and doubles into arrays, then
 * broadcasts
 * receives output from workers at t = tout
 */
int master( int nWrs, int master )
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int Mx; // M/nWrks gives domain decomposition
    double t = 0.0;
    char buffer[50];
    int M, MM;
    unsigned int N_max;
    double t0, t_end, dt_out, a, b, factor, D, dx, dt, t_out, dt_expl, mu;
    double* x_vals;
    double* U;

    //----MPI variables-----
    int numInts = 2;
    int numDbls = 6;
    int ierr, nProc, myID, rc;
    int *intParams;
    double *dblParams;

    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    fscanf(stdin, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %i",
           &t0, &t_end, &dt_out, &a, &b, &factor, &D, &MM);
    printf("t0: %lf t end: %lf  Number of CVs: %i  Factor: %3.2lf\n",
           t0, t_end, MM, factor);
        fflush(stdout);

    M = (b - a) * MM;
    dx = (double)(b - a)/M;
    dt_expl = (dx * dx)/(2 * D);
    dt = factor * dt_expl;
    N_max = (unsigned int)((t_end - t0)/dt + 1);
    t_out = max(dt_out, dt);
    mu = dt/dx;

    x_vals = ( double* ) calloc((M + 2), sizeof(double));
    U = ( double* ) calloc((M + 2), sizeof(double));
    xMesh( a, b, M, x_vals );

    intParams = ( int* ) malloc(( numInts ) * sizeof( int ));
    dblParams = ( double* ) malloc(( numDbls ) * sizeof( double ));

   // Pack arrays of variables to broadcast
    intParams[0] = N_max;
    intParams[1] = M;

    dblParams[0] = D;
    dblParams[1] = t_out;
    dblParams[2] = dt_out;
    dblParams[3] = dt;
    dblParams[4] = a;
    dblParams[5] = b;

    ierr = MPI_Bcast( intParams, numInts, MPI_INT, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    assert( !ierr );
    ierr = MPI_Bcast( dblParams, numDbls, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    assert( !ierr );

    // begin timestepping
    for (i = 1; i <= N_max; i++) {
//         sent to workers
//         flux( F, U, M, dx, D, t);
//         pde( F, U, M, D, mu, t, b );
        ierr = MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        assert( !ierr );
        t = i * dt;
        if ( t >= t_out ) {
            recv_output_MPI( nWrs, M, U ); 
            printf( "\nProfile at time: %lf, N-step: %u\n", t, i );
            fflush(stdout);
            compare( U, x_vals, M, D, t );
            t_out += dt_out;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nDone at time: %.6lf and Nsteps: %u\n\n", t, i );
    free( intParams );
    free( dblParams );
    free( U );
    free( x_vals );
    ierr = MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    return ierr;
}
/* Tasks of WORKER:
1. Unpack initial iparms and parms arrays, local Mz = Mz / nWRs
2. Exchange "boundary" values with neighbors
3. Do timestepping computation
4. Send output to MR every dtout
*/
int worker( int nWrs, int Me )
{
    double t = 0.0;
    unsigned int i;
    int ierr;
    int nodeLHS, nodeRHS;
    int numInts = 2;
    int numDbls = 6;
    int* intParams;
    double* dblParams;

    int N_max, M;
    double D, tout, dt_out, dt, a, b, mu, dx;
    double* U;
    double* F;
    double* x_vals;

    intParams = ( int* ) malloc(( numInts ) * sizeof( int ));
    dblParams = ( double* ) malloc(( numDbls ) * sizeof( double ));

    ierr = MPI_Bcast( intParams, numInts, MPI_INT, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    assert( !ierr );
    ierr = MPI_Bcast( dblParams, numDbls, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    assert( !ierr );

    N_max = intParams[0];
    M = intParams[1];

    D = dblParams[0];
    tout = dblParams[1];
    dt_out = dblParams[2];
    dt = dblParams[3];
    a = dblParams[4];
    b = dblParams[5];
    mu = (M * dt)/(b - a);
    dx = (double)(b - a)/M;

    x_vals = calloc((M + 2), sizeof(double));
    U = calloc((M + 2), sizeof(double));
    F = calloc((M + 2), sizeof(double));

    xMesh( a, b, M, x_vals );
    init( M, U ); //set u(a) = 1, u(b) = 0

    for ( i = 1; i <=N_max; i++ ) {
        ierr = MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD ); 
        assert( !ierr );
        t = i * dt;
//          flux( nWrs, Me, F, U, M, dx, D, t );
//          pde( nWrs, Me, F, U, M, D, mu, t, b );
        if (t >= tout) {
            send_output_MPI( nWrs, Me, M, U );
            tout += dt_out;
        }
    }

    free ( intParams );
    free ( dblParams );
    deleteMem ( U, F, x_vals );
    fflush(stdout);
    ierr = MPI_Barrier( MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    return ierr;
}
// only done by master
void recv_output_MPI( int nWrs, int M, double* U )
{
    int Ime;
    unsigned int i, source;
    unsigned int msgtag = 1000;
    int ierr, offset;
    int chunkSize = (M + 2)/nWrs;
    unsigned int end;
    double* tmp;

    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Datatype Mytype;

    ierr = MPI_Type_contiguous( chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, &Mytype );
    assert ( !ierr );
    ierr = MPI_Type_commit( &Mytype );
    assert ( !ierr );

    for ( i = 1; i <= nWrs; i++ ) {
        source = i;
        msgtag = i * msgtag;
        offset = (i - 1) * chunkSize;
        end = i * chunkSize;
        tmp = ( double* ) malloc(( chunkSize ) * sizeof( double ));
        ierr = MPI_Recv( &offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, msgtag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status ); 
        ierr = MPI_Recv( tmp, chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
        assert ( !ierr );
        for ( i = offset; i < end; i++ ){
            U[i] = tmp[i];
        }
    }
    ierr = MPI_Type_free( &Mytype );
    assert ( !ierr );
    free( tmp );
    return;
}
void send_output_MPI( int nWrs, int Me, int M, double* U )//TODO:fix
{
    int ierr, msgtag, i;
    int start = (Me - 1) * (M/nWrs)+1;
    int chunkSize = (M + 2)/nWrs;
    unsigned int offset = ( Me - 1 ) * chunkSize;
    unsigned int end = Me * chunkSize;
    double* sendVals  = calloc( chunkSize, sizeof( double ));
    assert( sendVals != NULL );
    MPI_Datatype Mytype;

    ierr = MPI_Type_contiguous( chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, &Mytype );
    assert ( !ierr );
    ierr = MPI_Type_commit( &Mytype );
    assert ( !ierr );

    msgtag = Me * 1000;
    ierr = MPI_Send( &offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, msgtag, MPI_COMM_WORLD ); 

//     memcpy( &sendVals[0], &U[offset], chunkSize * sizeof( double ));
    // send part of the U array
    ierr = MPI_Send( sendVals, chunkSize, Mytype, MASTER, msgtag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    assert( !ierr );
    ierr = MPI_Type_free( &Mytype );
    assert ( !ierr );
    free( sendVals );
    return;
}
/*  produces nodal values for x-array
    takes interval endpoints [a,b] as double and
    M as number of nodal values
    returns pointer to x-array
    precondition: x-array allocated in main,
    postcondition: x-array populated in main
*/
void xMesh( double a, double b, int M, double* x )
{
    unsigned int i;
    double dx = (b - a)/M;
    x[0] = a;
    for (i = 1; i < M+1; i++)
        x[i] = a + (i - 0.5)*dx;
    x[M + 1] = b;
    return;
}
/* function: init
 * takes: endpoints, a and b, x-array and pde struct
 * returns: nothing
 * precondition: U and x array initialized, x-array defined
 * postcondition: u_init set in U array
 */
void init( int M, double* U )
{
    U[0] = 1.0;
    U[M+1] = 0.0;
}

void deleteMem( double* F, double* U, double* x )
{
    free( F );
    free( U );
    free( x );
    return;
}
/* function: compare - compares numerical approximation against the
 *           closed-form solution
 * params: U - pointer to u array
           x - pointer to x (spatial) array
           M - array size
           D - diffusion coefficient
           t - time
   precondition: arrays initialized and containing values
   postcondition: file 'plot.out' appended with values for plotting
*/
void compare( double* U, double* x, int M, double D, double t )
{
    unsigned int j;
    double error, u_exact;
    double err_max = 0.0;
    double val = 2.0 * sqrt( D * t );

    for ( j = 0; j < M+2; j++ ) {
        u_exact = erfc( x[j]/val );
        error = fabs( u_exact - U[j] );
        fprintf( stdout, "%10.8lf\t%18.16lf\t%18.16lf\n", x[j], U[j], u_exact );
        fflush(stdout);
        err_max = max( error, err_max );
    }
    return;
}
```

The text file read in looks something like:

`t0   tEnd  dtout a    b    factor  D    MM`

`0.0  1.0   1.0   0.0  1.0   0.9     0.1   8`

I've tried using memcpy and a for loop to copy the passed arrays back to the U-array, but nothing is working well this morning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to (asking questions on) stack overflow! When asking questions about coding problems, it helps to reduce your code to a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please consider doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I see:

First off, I hope that you are only calling this very few times. If not, then you need to restructure your logic so that you only create an MPI_Datatype in the initialization stage of your algorithm. Creating a datatype every time you want to send information is slow for obvious reasons.

[If the size of the datatype is the only thing changing, then a better alternative would be to simply stop using MPI_Datatypes. You're seemingly only using them for contiguous data anyway, so you can specify the count in `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv` properly each time you're sending a message. This is the approach I took in the below rewrite]

Secondly, the amount of information you are sending seems to be wrong. That is, you are setting up `sendVals` to be of size `chunkSize`. Therefore, when you send part of the `U` array, you should only be sending `chunkSize` doubles.

```
ierr = MPI_Send(sendVals, chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, msgtag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

works, or the alternative using your MPI_Datatype would be

```
ierr = MPI_Send(sendVals, 1, Mytype, MASTER, msgtag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Likewise, on the receiving end of thing, you should only be receiving either 1 of your datatype or `chunkSize` `MPI_DOUBLE`s.

Personally, I would write what you have as follows:

```
void send_output_MPI( int nWrs, int Me, int M, double* U )
{
    int ierr, msgtag, i;
    int start = (Me - 1) * (M/nWrs)+1;
    int chunkSize = (M + 2)/nWrs;
    unsigned int offset = ( Me - 1 ) * chunkSize;

    msgtag = Me * 1000;
    // send part of the U array
    ierr = MPI_Send( &U[offset], chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, msgtag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    return;
}

// only done by master
void recv_output_MPI( int nWrs, int M, double* U )
{
    unsigned int i, source;
    unsigned int msgtag = 1000;
    int ierr, offset;
    int chunkSize = (M + 2)/nWrs;
    MPI_Status status;

    for ( i = 1; i <= nWrs; i++ ) {
        source = i;
        msgtag = i * msgtag;
        offset = (i - 1)*chunkSize;
        ierr = MPI_Recv( &U[offset], chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, source, msgtag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );

    }
    return;
}
```

If you can calculate `offset` correctly on the master rank then there is no need to send it. If you cannot calculate it, then you would have to perform the two sends/recvs that you had previously. Also, there is no need to make temporary send/recv buffers if you can put them directly into the `U` array. This appears to be what you were doing with your `memcopy` calls.

Finally, I make no guarantees that you are properly calculating the indices `offset`, `end`, and the size `chunkSize`. I only copied your values. You can imagine obviously that the amount you send must be equal to the amount you receive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: _"Creating a datatype every time you want to send information is slow for obvious reasons."_ This is not necessarily (and most likely not at all) true. Creating and registering a datatype is a local operation and on modern CPUs is extremely fast, or at least faster than the latency of most network interconnects. Of course, it doesn't mean that one should unnecessarily create datatypes when that could be evaded.

Comment: While it's true that the communication will certainly be the slowest part of these functions, there is no reason to constantly be creating and freeing the type every time you want to send anything. Just as you would never suggest anyone to constantly be allocating and deallocating an array on the heap; instead, you should keep one array and overwrite the data.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. To answer your questions, this function only is called when we want to check if our approximation is close to the analytic solution. The `offset` and `chunkSize` are the same as used in the domain decomposition used elsewhere. Lastly, would it be better to use MPI_Gather instead of the send and recv here, since we are gathering all of the sub-arrays in the Master process?

Comment: It depends on how your `U` array is stored. It appears to me that everyone has allocated memory for the entire `U` array, but they only work on one section of it. This isn't the usual use case for `MPI_Gather`, but it should still work if you're careful about the send/recv buffer indexing. Usually, `MPI_Gather` is performed where each MPI process only has allocated a small amount of memory for their local problem. Only the master rank has allocated the full space. If you're not calling this that often/worried about performance, I would keep it as send/recvs.

Comment: Got the send/recv working now. Thanks again for your help.